# Editor throwing me a warning, error message on my code

Tags: javascript, debugging

```
// Find events for this date
for ( var i = 0, event; event = plugin.settings.events[i]; i++ ) 
{
    if ( event[plugin.settings.end] >= begin && event[plugin.settings.begin] < end ) 
    {
        // Append matches to list
        var summary    = event[plugin.settings.summary],
        beginTime  = (( event[plugin.settings.begin] > begin ) ? event[plugin.settings.begin] : begin ).toTimeString().substr(0,5),
        endTime    = (( event[plugin.settings.end] < end ) ? event[plugin.settings.end] : end ).toTimeString().substr(0,5),
        timeString = beginTime + "-" + endTime,
        $listItem  = $("<li class='ui-event-item' data-icon='false'><a href='#' class='event-item-link' rel='"+ event.eid +"'><h3></h3><p></p></a></li>").appendTo($listview);

        plugin.settings.listItemFormatter( $listItem, timeString, summary, event );
    }
}
```

The code is working just fine, however my editor is throwing me a warning/error on this line:

```
for ( var i = 0, event; event = plugin.settings.events[i]; i++ ) {
```

Error msg: Expected a conditional expression, and instead saw an assignment.

Anyone know why it is throwing me this "message" ?

Comment: This is Javascript, not Java. Or not?

Comment: Thanks for a really clarifying answer :)

Comment: Note that's not an _actual_ JavaScript error.

Comment: as I said, my EDITOR is giving me a warning/error message, and I do not know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Expected a conditional expression, and instead saw an assignment."*

This means exactly what it says. The middle expression in the `for` statement is usually some sort of conditional expression, but you've used an assignment. The editor thinks that `=` is a typo that should've been `==` or `===`.

In your case it (presumably) *isn't* a typo: you actually do want to do the assignment at that point and it works in the `for` statement because in JS assignments still evaluate to a value that the `for` can treat as truthy or falsey. Some people consider this bad practice because at first glance it does look like a typo, although on second glance it's reasonably clear that it's not.

So you could rewrite the `for` to *not* do an assignment at that point. Or you could just ignore the error/warning message - **this isn't an actual JS error,** it is a style thing.

> *"Suggestion on how to "rewrite it" do get rid of the message?"*

Well if `plugin.settings.events` is an array or array-like object that doesn't have any falsey values in it (or undefined elements) then you can do this:

```
for (var i = 0, event; i < plugin.settings.events.length; i++ ) {
    event = plugin.settings.events[i];
    // etc.
```

Comment: Thanks. So no problem then? As I said, not a skilled developer. Suggestion on how to "rewrite it" do get rid of the message? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It's not a problem as far as your code working as intended. It's just possibly an issue if somebody else has to maintain your code and doesn't realise that it is valid JS as is. Answer updated with one possible rewrite...

Answer (score 1):

`event = plugin.settings.events[i]` is being assigned inside the for statement.